# Docker swarm - Manager node cannot access the containers in worker node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In our docker swarm environment, there is 1 manager nodes and 2 worker nodes.
We also installed portainer,swarm and the portainer agent's &swarm agents on all nodes.

Yesterday, one of the virtual servers which worker node installed rebooted unexpectedly.
When we check the docker service it was stopped. restarted the docker service with using this command:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Then all the containers seem to work fine on the worker node. But when we check the containers by the portainer which runs on a master node, the containers look stopped. Swarmpit reports that the worker's nodes active and ready.
What could be the problem?

Worker Node:

[image: Worker Node]

Master node - running containers
[image]

Swarmpit
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We find out that the firewall caused the error.
After rebotting CentOS, the firewall is enabled automatically and it conflicted with the docker engine so we disabled the firewall with this command:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```